# Internet Explorer is pointing me to a COMMENTED OUT line and saying it's an error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

IE is pointing me to the middle line of

```
this.DboChart = this.GetDboChart(); // "Deals By Offer" chart
    //this.PpvdbaChart = this.GetPpvdbaChart(); // "% Pipeline Value of Deals By Area"
    this.Mdcc = this.GetMdccChart(); // "MSfC Deals - Cumulative Count"
```

and saying

> Object doesn't support property or method 'GetPpvdbaChart'

Makes no sense. Assuming it wasn't commented out, I still have no idea where it gets the idea that the simple and valid function

```
Calculator.prototype.GetPpvdbaChart = function ( )
{
    var areaData = new Array();     
    var calc = this;            
    this.Data.forEach(function(reg, idx){
        areaData.push({ value     : reg.NumOpportunities, 
                        color     : calc.ColorStack[idx % calc.ColorStack.length],
                        highlight : calc.HighlightColor, 
                        label     : reg.RegionName });  
    });
    return new Chart(document.getElementById("pipeline-deals-by-area").getContext("2d")).Pie(calc.areaData,calc.AreaOptions);       
}
```

isn't supported.

Comment: You sure? Can you post the screen please.

Comment: Is it showing error on line where its commented or where its defined?